# Save just the date attribute of updated_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form element in my Rails Application for changing the publication date of a post (not the time).  I did this so I could use a datepicker element from jquery-ui and have drop downs menus for the time.

[image]

I'd like to update the "updated_at" attribute to the publication date.  However, I'm getting an error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  null value in column "updated_at" violates not-null constraint
: UPDATE "steps" SET "updated_at" = NULL WHERE "steps"."id" = 472
```

Here is my form (which can save the time correctly but not the date):

```
 <%= semantic_form_for [@project, @step], :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
    <%= f.inputs do%>
    <div id="publishedOn">
        <span class="label" style="margin-left:9px">Published on</span>
           <%= f.text_field :published_on, :value=> (@step.updated_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")) %>  at <%= f.time_select :updated_at, :class=>"btn dropdown-toggle", :ampm=> true, :ignore_date=>true%>
      </div>
<% end %>
```

steps_controller:

```
def update
    @step = @project.steps.find_by_position(params[:id])
    published = String(params[:published_on])
    published = published.gsub("/", "-")
    @step.update_attributes(:updated_at => published)
end
```

step.rb:

```
class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :position

  has_ancestry :orphan_strategy => :adopt

    attr_accessible :description, :name, :position, :project_id, :images_attributes, :parent_id, :ancestry, :updated_at, :published_on
    belongs_to :project
    has_many :images, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => :true

    validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

Do I need to reformat the published_on date parameter to update the updated_at date?

Comment: Seems like `published` might be nil in your `update` action.

Comment: If I decide to just use the published_on attribute, how can I update the date and the time separately (since I have a text field for the date and drop down menus for the time?)

Comment: If you print out `String(params[:published_on])` in your controller, what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

The `updated_at` model attribute is not really meant for any purpose but to record the last time the model object was updated. It can be overridden, but it's not good Rails practice to do so. The errors you're witnessing are likely the result of trying to override a core attribute.

The solution I've implemented in the past is to create a separate attribute, perhaps something like `published_at`. You can operate on this however you'd like, while keeping `updated_at` in place for the purpose it's meant for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  So if I decide to just use the published_on attribute, how can I update the date and the time separately?

Comment: By default, `updated_at` is typed as a timestamp, so you'd optimally pass a timestamp to your `update` action.

Comment: What do you get if you print out String(params[:published_on]) in your controller?

Comment: I'm now getting the error ActiveRecord::MultiparameterAssignmentErrors in StepsController#update: 1 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes

These are the parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"FxFbv9OFzCiYjNknZKUtwyAXR99uuOvy8uplv1cKaZE=",
 "step"=>{"description"=>"<p>Project description</p>\r\n",
 "published_on"=>"05/30/2013",
 "published_on(4i)"=>"15",
 "published_on(5i)"=>"19"},
 "commit"=>"Update Step",
 "project_id"=>"92",
 "id"=>"0"}

Comment: It looks as though you're getting multiple parameters for the `published_on` parameter. Something is fishy with your form... I think it's passing in the time (hours/minutes) as `published_on`, when `published_on` should in fact be a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
@step.update_attributes(:updated_at => published)
```

Rails seems to be complaining that you're trying to update `update_at` to `nil`. So what's likely happening is that the variable `published` is nil.

Answer (score 0):

You really should use a new attribute for the publishing date. You can use the :updated_at attribute but whenever you update the entry in the database it will be overwritten.
If you are using Rails you know it's a *VERY* opinionated framework, so stick with the conventions. Besides that you are not saving a lot of space in database or getting an optimization.